# response impulse function

Tags: signal-processing

my question is related to time series modeling  in  signal  form,i have such question,suppose  we  have  time series  data  $y_1........y_n$,how can we represent  in  impulse response form?as i understood when   i  read  different  literature's,we can represent  it into     rational form,as a   ratio  of two  polynomials  transformed into  z-domain,so  is it  right  this?and then we  should estimate  coefficient  ,but  why  we  need   data  of  our time  series?where we use it?here is picture  of this form
[image]

where  G  is gain of the system,i will add link  of one topic about filters

http://dsp.vscht.cz/konference_matlab/MATLAB06/prispevky/marcek_milan2/marcek_milan2.pdf

thanks  a lot of

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read about the basics, to grasp the concepts. Quick take:

First, an **impulse response** $h[n]$ does not characterizes a time series, but a LTI **filter**.

Second, a time series (a signal) $y[n]$ can (sometimes, under some conditions, and in some restricted sense [*]) be represented as the output of a LTI filter fed by a stationary white noise $x[n]$.

Third, digital signals and filters can be written alternatively (instead of as a function of "time" $n$), as Z transforms: $Y(z)=H(z) X(z)$ . Most LTI filters that are of practical use correspond to a rational function (which can be characterized by its poles and zeros), which correspond to [ARMA modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model).

[*] When and in what sense? In a stochastic (probabilistic) sense, and mostly restricted just to second-order statistics (correlations), when the time series can be assumed to be stationary